# Make Input Field Look Disabled Without Using Disabled Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have an `asp.net webform` and I have a `datepicker` field. The calendar is displayed when the user clicks on my icon at the end of my field.

What I want is for the `input` field to look disabled.  I have tried adding the attribute `disabled` and `readonly="true"` but when I do this my date selected is not passed through in my session.

So I need another way of doing this as I said the date entered is passed in session.

I have added my `background-color` but I need to stop the blinking cursor displaying if the user clicks in the field.

I have tried adding `style="color: transparent !important"` to my `input` field but this doesn't work.  Is there another way?

I have added my `HTML` and `JQuery` to show how my `datepicker` currently works.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label ID="Step03StartDateLabel" class="col-sm-4 control-label" runat="server" Text="Date you would like us to start *" AssociatedControlID="Step03StartDateField"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <asp:TextBox ID="Step03StartDateField" runat="server" class="form-control" ToolTip="Click the calendar to select a date." style="background-color: #eeeeee; color: transparent !important;" TabIndex="-1" />
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="Step03StartDateFieldCalendar" style="cursor: pointer"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="reqStep03startDateErrorMessage" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="Step03StartDateField" ErrorMessage="Please select a date you would want us to start." />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function ()
{
     $("#MainContent_Step03StartDateField").datepicker(
     {
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          minDate: '0',
     });

     $("#Step03StartDateFieldCalendar").click(function ()
     {
          $("#MainContent_Step03StartDateField").datepicker("show");
     });

     $("#MainContent_Step03EndDateField").datepicker(
     {
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          minDate: '1'
     });

     $("#Step03EndDateFieldCalendar").click(function ()
     {
          $("#MainContent_Step03EndDateField").datepicker("show");
     });
});
```

Comment: you could use `cursor: default` and prevent a click via javascript

Comment: [I don't understand the problem with "readonly"](http://jsfiddle.net/wnx19q2e/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy As I said in my post, the date doesn't pass in my session as it passes it as an empty string. so I can not use `disabled` or `readonly`

Comment: [But why? The form data will be submit correctly.](http://jsfiddle.net/n69nes9q/) Is this some ASP thing I'm not wrapping my head around? (Never developed for ASP)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Not sure if its just an `asp` thing but when I debug, although the date I selected is displayed in my field, the session for the field comes back as an empty string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the style `pointer-events: none;` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)) to your textbox:

```
<input type='text' style='pointer-events: none;' />
```

In addition to your previous styles, it will remove mouse events on your element (including the blinking cursor).

> **None**
>
> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events
> may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
> pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse
> events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
> appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
> capture/bubble phases.

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bppgcjgf/

Comment: That's a good question. MDN's documentation even says it works since Chrome 1.0.

Comment: I see what you mean, it does not work once it has the DatePicker attached,

Comment: @HanletEscaño This is working great except for the issue stated above about when my datepicker is displayed.  Could this be handled in the JQuery?

Comment: Not sure what issue you are talking about @murday1983

Comment: @HanletEscaño That the cursor is re-displayed when the `datepicker` is displayed. Your solution works for if the user tries to click in the field but as soon as I click on my image and the calendar is displayed, the cursor is displayed in the field

Comment: you can still use keyboard to tab into the field and enter data with `pointer-events: none`